# VBA loop until function is true, changing passed value each time

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that adds new users. I'm trying to auto generate the username, which needs to be unique. I have a function checkUsername that takes the string passed and checks the db table to see if that username exists. It returns false if the username exists and true if not.

What I'm trying to do is if the username already exists then add a number on to the end and check again. I want to keep looping until a unqiue username is found. Heres my attempt at a loop below, however its returning usernames that already exist. Also I prefer it to increment the number rather than just adding it to the end. Currently the pattern ends up being username1, username12, username123.

```
'Generate username
Dim Username As String
Username = generateUsername(LCase(Left(FirstName, 1) & LastName))

Function generateUsername(Username As String) As String

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

    Do While checkUsername(Username)
        If checkUsername(Username) Then
           Exit Do
        Else
           Username = Username & i
           i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop

    generateUsername = Username

End Function
```

Comment: Not related to the question, but you also need to test the length to make sure that after you "build" a username this way that it will fit in the backing field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is, when the username exists already (see Andre's answer for the code that will accomplish this a different way):

- check what the previous "i" number was, as a string, to see how many characters I need to cut off the end of username
- set username equal to a substring of username, which will cut off the last X characters (X being the number of characters the previous "i" was)
- add the new "i" to the end username

That will solve your naming issue.

For your issue of looking for unique names, no one will be able to help with that until we can see what the code looks like for the "checkUsername" function. Make sure that that function is returning the value you are expecting, first.  I suspect the problem is in there.

EDIT:

I also don't understand why you have an "If/Else" statement in your loop.  You already determined that it was true.  See below for simplified version (again, assuming I got the code right for VB...I usually do it in C#):

```
Do While Not checkUsername(NewName)        
    NewName  = Username & i
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Ya. I completely missed it the first time I read it.  That explains why he never reaches the "Else".

Answer (score 2):

I assume `checkUsername()` returns true if the username exists?

Then your `If` condition is wrong - you want to exit if it **doesn't** exist.

Your loop gets clearer if you use two variables:

```
Function generateUsername(origUsername As String) As String

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Username As String

    i = 1
    Username = origUsername

    Do While checkUsername(Username)
'        If Not checkUsername(Username) Then
'           Exit Do
'        Else
           Username = origUsername & i
           i = i + 1
'        End If
    Loop

    generateUsername = Username

End Function
```

Edit: as pointed out by Joel, the additional `checkUsername()` in the loop isn't needed. Since it probably involves a `DLookup` or similar, it is actually harmful to performance.
I commented it out above.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but this is the corrected version!

Change your code to this instead:

```
Dim Username As String
Username = generateUsername(LCase(Left(FirstName, 1) & LastName))

Function generateUsername(Username As String) As String
Dim NewName  as String
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
NewName = Username
Do While checkUsername(NewName)
    If checkUsername(NewName) Then
       Exit Do
    Else
       NewName  = Username & i
       i = i + 1
    End If
Loop

generateUsername = NewName

End Function
```

Comment: This assumes that the previous "i" is only one character in perpetuity (if I remember my VB correctly).  You should do a character count on "i.ToString" to ensure you are getting rid of the right number of characters.

Comment: Yes, this will return funny results for i >= 10